# send email C# using smtp server with username password authentification

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail, smtpclient

I have a piece of code that sends email.. heres the code

This is not working for me. This a remote smtp service ... and i double checked that email web access works fine .. i can login using the gui, recieve and send emails.

But when i try to do it through code .. it fails with the message ...

> {System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 No AUTH command has been given.

Can anybody advise ... and also they dont have EWS exposed ie.e exchange web service ./.. this is the way to go ..

port is 25 and no SSL or TLS

```
Button b = sender as Button;
try
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(senderEmail, recieverEmail, "afdasfas", "safasfa");
    //MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(senderEmail, recieverEmail, subject, subject);
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailclient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(EmailSmtpServer, outgoingPort);
    System.Net.NetworkCredential auth = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);
    mailclient.Host = EmailSmtpServer;
    mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    mailclient.Credentials = auth;
    mailclient.Send(msg);
    MessageBox.Show(b.Content + ":WORKED");
}
catch (Exception e4)
{
    MessageBox.Show(b.Content + ": " +e4.Message);
    MessageBox.Show(b.Content + ": " + e4.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: can you put your code in a code block?  makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want to set

```
mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Read more about this option [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials.aspx).

---

You should also test that you can actually send email through that smtp server.

Try connecting via telnet and authorizing. There are also plenty of services that will let you send a test message online (http://pingability.com/smtptest.jsp for example).

Comment: No .. i am sorry thas a typo .. i was trying all options ..

i will edit the post ... 

i get this exception when i trying run the code

{System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 No AUTH command has been given.
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)

Comment: i can telnet to that remote smtp service ... when i use auth login and then provide username and password in base64 format , i can login ... so i guess the problem in with C# code ... and sendMail does not send "auth login" command or does not send username/password in base64 ... do you think you can point me to blog/site which has this corrected ... i tried a bunch of them and it didnt work for me ... thank you.

Comment: @KK, The code you have looks good. Are you passing the username and password to the NetworkCredential constructor in plain text?

Comment: i pass it as base64 .. i can write a C# script and do the selnet thing .. and send email .. everything works fine in Tx, USA ..state where i am located ... even from my home network .... but does not work when i run it from my client in columbia ...

Answer (score 1):

**System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 No AUTH command has been given.**

you are attempting to login without sending the **AUTH** command first. this is why your web gui, which auto-inserts it's own **AUTH** commands works but your current client-application is not receiving a command from you to relay onto the server, but the server **requires authentication**.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to Add `mailclient.EnableSsl = true;`

Comment: No .. i am sorry thas a typo .. i was trying all options ..

i will edit the post ... 

i get this exception when i trying run the code

{System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 No AUTH command has been given.
   at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)

Comment: the remote smtp service does not need smtp enabled

Comment: i can telnet to that remote smtp service ... when i use auth login and then provide username and password in base64 format , i can login ... so i guess the problem in with C# code ... and sendMail does not send "auth login" command or does not send username/password in base64 ... do you think you can point me to blog/site which has this corrected ... i tried a bunch of them and it didnt work for me ... thank you.